# Script error in Google Earth Engine: File larger than 512kb

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, save

Anyone knows why is this happening in Google Earth Engine? It does not let me to save my script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had a lot of geometries as geometry collection, so I just set them as feature collections and the script was saved. I do not know why was that, but it worked.

Comment: Same here. It stills shows the message, but at least allow you to save the file